# how to insert a record in middle table in entityframework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-6

I have two basic tables (nurse, patient)
and there is a middle table which represents the result of a medical exam consists of (id - patient_id - nurse_id - reslt)

so I made a new result and gave it its values then add it to my DBEntities then save but this problem had occurred

where is the problem exactly?

[image: problem appears on save the record]

Comment: where do you get id in  "res.nurse_id = id" ?

Comment: basically I set the variable id=1 statically  (just for test ,,, there is a record in nurse table with id = 1)

Comment: Post and see inner exception for more details please

Comment: he tells me that there is no dbo.res as [this photo](https://ibb.co/rxnyTjP) although it exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the generated entity ,,, I only deleted that entity and created another one (using generate from existing database) and it's working fine now